# Is it possibile to include Sub inside the user-Type in openoffice? VBA

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

User-Type is the kind of structure. I'm wondering if i can have sub delaration inside it. Something like:

```
Type myType
  myParam1 As String
  myParam2 As Long
  ...
  Sub mySub(param)
    'here I want some code for printing/showing params value
  End Sub
End Type
```

I ask because i have problem with printing value of the myParam, when data are in an array of items of myType. After populating myArr with myType items, statment

```
print myArr(i).myParam1
```

gives me empty string.

Comment: This facility is not present in Microsoft VBA so I would be surprised if it was available in LibreOffice VBA.

Comment: Please post a [reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. Also, the language is called LibreOffice Basic, not VBA which is only for Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create an array of a declared type, be sure to use the `Dim As New` syntax.

```vb
Type myType
  myParam1 As String
  myParam2 As Long
End Type

Sub mySub
    Dim myArr(2) As New myType
    myArr(0).myParam1 = "A"
    myArr(0).myParam2 = 1
    myArr(1).myParam1 = "B"
    myArr(1).myParam2 = 2
    For i = 0 to Ubound(myArr) - 1
        Print myArr(i).myParam1
    Next
End Sub
```

As for adding subroutines in a `Type` statement, it is not in [the documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Other_Instructions). On the other hand, that's an integral part of [Python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python), one of the most popular LibreOffice scripting languages.

```
class myClass:
    myAttr1 = ""
    myAttr2 = 0
    def myFunc(self, param):
        self.myAttr2 = param
        print(self.myAttr1)

myArr = [myClass(), myClass()]
myArr[0].myAttr1 = "A"
myArr[0].myAttr2 = 1
myArr[1].myAttr1 = "B"
myArr[1].myAttr2 = 2
for myObj in myArr:
    myObj.myFunc(3)
```

Comment: For me Python would be best option for  data analyses. Unfortunately this code is part of macro that's used in OpenOffice file that is copied and used by many causal users. That mean no Python on their devices.

Comment: Are you sure there are users who have systems without Python? Most unix-based systems come with Python, and Windows-based distributions of LibreOffice ship with Python. Generally, I would assume that if a system has LibreOffice, or the latest version of Apache OpenOffice, then it can run a Python macro. Occasionally an extra package may need to be installed, but not in most cases.

Comment: That's worth of checking on a other computer.